# Use multiple methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, rounding

How to use multiple methods in a code? First it asks for the size of an array, then for the numbers of the element. One method is rounding numbers with a special rule.
Second method is a void method which modifies the array. Third method is making a new array with the modified values and returns to this array.

```
package tombtombbekerekit;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TombTombbeKerekit {
    public static int round(int osszeg)
    {
        int last_Digit = osszeg % 10;
    if(last_Digit  < 3) 
        return osszeg - last_Digit;
    else if(last_Digit > 7)
        return osszeg + (10 - last_Digit);
    else 
        return osszeg - (last_Digit) + 5;
    }

```
public static void roundSelf(int [] numbers)
{
    int[] array = numbers;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    return;
}

public static int [] roundNew(int [] numbers)
{
    int [] newArray = new int[numbers.length];
    return newArray;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Kérem az összegek számát: ");
    int size = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Kérem az összegeket: ");
    int [] array = new int[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
    {
        array[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    int [] kerek = roundNew(array);
    System.out.println("Kerekítve: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < kerek.length; i++)
        System.out.println(kerek[i]);
}
```

}

Comment: Use `if-else` ?

Comment: Write a function that get a number and round it with your own rules!

Comment: There are no built-in methods for this, no. Write your own.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I don't know why this question earns a minus but okay, I understand, newbies are all stupids and their questions too. No problem!

Comment: It's a little bit like doubling it,  rounding to even, then halving it.

Comment: I downvoted this question cause you show no attempt to solving your problem yourself. It reads like "do my work for me". Stackoverflow is about helping you with specific problems, not writing the code for you. You may want to read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I don't ask for the solution! Only asking about that the round has any arguments to done the job. Sorry for the bad questioning!

Comment: The question is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write your own function. Just find the rule for the rounding. You can use `n%10` to get the last digit of an integer named `n`.

I've written something but haven't tested it, I believe it should work. Check it out:

```
public int weirdRounding(int n)
{
    int last_Digit = n % 10;
    if(last_Digit  < 3) 
        return n - last_Digit;
    else if(last_Digit > 7)
        return n + (10 - last_Digit);
    else // the last digit is 3,4,5,6,7
        return n - (last_Digit) + 5;
}
```

Note: You should probably make this code more readable if you're going to use it. For example define `int LOWER_BOUND = 3` and `int UPPER_BOUND = 7` instead of using '3' and '7', you could also wrap the ugly expressions with functions (e.g. roundUp, roundToFive ..). #Magic_Numbers_Are_Bad

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I'll try it and try to make mine too!